# What's the best and 'fastest' way to secure data on an external HDD?

Tags: windows-7, security, external-hard-drive, storage

I have a transcend 1 TB HDD that has some sensitive data in it. I want no one to be able to access that drive. I know that there's an option to encrypt the whole drive but I think it will be ridiculous to actually encrypt 1TB of data.

I want to know of a middle ground between encryption and basic folder hiding. It should be more of a deterrent than an actual encryption. Enough so that the person who connected the drive to his/her computer must not be able to get access to it by clicking a few buttons in the OS environment.

Comment: Anything that is not encryption is equal to zero security.  Even using Windows permissions is not good enough.  I can access any local Administrator account on any computer within 20 minutes.

Comment: My target group that I want not to access the drive is not too dedicated on the idea of breaking the security. Windows permission is a bit too easy to crack. I am thinking more about playing with the file record of the file system on the drive. Since this data is just passive and is not needed to run an OS, I don't mind doing anything like that. 

I am open to a suggestion of some software that does something like that,

Comment: What you want is not clear. Playing with the file system isn't something you should be doing

Comment: Why is it 'ridiculous' to encrypt your drive? If you are concerned about speed, you should know that symmetric encryption is quite fast. If you encrypt the whole drive (for example with TrueCrypt as Jim recommended) you will not see much slow down in performance after the initial encryption of the drive (it will encrypt/decrypt on the fly so you don't need to keep encrypting files).

Comment: I will try Truecrypt. Thanks. I would however like to know if there's some other great way to "hide" files perhaps in such a way that no one is able to  even get those files by means of searching. I am not really looking for "encryption" here since I want this security for the whole of the 1 TB drive and for casual uses. I just want to create a deterrence for the prying eyes so that they can not just extract the data simply by searching or enabling their system to show system files..

Comment: *Best* and *Fastest* are inversely proportional

Answer (score 7):

Consider using True Crypt.  You will be able to create an encrypted container and map it as a drive letter.

http://www.truecrypt.org/

Comment: This is the route that I would go. If you have TrueCrypt on your primary system drive and set this container with the same passphrase, you can opt to have this file auto mount whenever the computer is booted.

Answer (score 2):

> I think it will be ridiculous to actually encrypt 1TB of data.

It sounds like you only have a small amount of data that you want to protect.

Install 7-zip and put the data you want to protect in a password-protected .7z file.  Name the file something innocuous like crashlogs.7z or similar. This will probably be the least work and the quickest thing to do if you only have a few hundred MB of sensitive data or so, and your data will be really encrypted.

> I am thinking more about playing with the file record of the file system on the drive.

You could change the permissions on the file to only allow you to read and write. Do this on the top-level folder containing the data so you can tell the permissions to be inheritable from it.

You'll need to right click the folder and go to the Security tab.  You'll need to uncheck the box that says "Inherit permissions from parent" or similar, and then add a permission entry that only has your user account (don't even add Administrator) and set yourself as the owner.  Don't mess with deny permissions - users that don't show up on the list can't access and deny will have side effects you don't want.

Any account on any Windows system with admin permissions can take ownership and reset the permissions, but as you'll find out by doing the above, it's not terribly obvious IMHO to a casual non-technical user to do that.  If they know a competent IT person though, such a person could find out in a manner of minutes or so how to undo it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows 7 you can use Windows [BitLocker](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/bitlocker), its fast and easy (just type BitLocker in Start menu to access BitLocker, it will automatically detect your externall HDD and add to list to turn on BitLocker for that drive)

and if you want to use other programs you can use these two:

[TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) (its POWERFUL and FREE but a little configuration needed, you can find its instruction in [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) site)

[SafeGuard](http://www.usbsafeguard.com/) (its FAST and SIMPLE but its not free)

Answer (score 0):

If the disk is already NTFS formatted, NTFS encryption can be applied on a file-by-file base.

Comment: Maybe some additional details? Links to documentation about it, maybe post how to enable encryption, any restrictions with encrypted files (i.e. not to lose your password or recovery certificate, etc)?